# Headers and Footers only show up after the fourth page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am making a document with headers and footers. I want them on every page, including the title page. I have chosen `fancyhdr` for this task, but I'm open to alternatives.

My minimal working example (compiled with XeLaTex) is supposed/intended to clear the headers and footers on every page and replace it with an image on top, and text on the bottom. But this does not happen on the title page, the table of contents, Chapter 1 and the beginning of Chapter 2. After that, the image and text are generated as intended.

How can I fix this and print the material on every page?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[hl]{\includegraphics{graphs/dataset17b.pdf}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[fl]{\emph{ \tiny \lipsum[1]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\Huge{\textbf{Title page}}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\chapter{Executive Summary}
The executive summary gets its own page.
\clearpage

\chapter{Now for the good stuff}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum
\section{Section 3}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that certain commands, such as `\titlepage` have their own `\thispagestyle` that may over-ride your setting. Perhaps you can over-ride the over-ride by rearranging the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my above comment into an answer:

All you need to do is add `\thispagestyle{plain}` to each page, then the page number will appear in the footer. If you want more, use `\thispagestyle{fancy}` on each page. Here is how it works with the footer:

```
% code at top
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\Huge{\textbf{Title page}}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\clearpage
\chapter{Executive Summary}
\thispagestyle{plain}
The executive summary gets its own page.
\clearpage
% rest of code
```

Comment: With class `report`, `\tableofcontents` is a `\chapter*{…}` and therefore already uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Also `\chapter{…}` already uses `\thispagestyle{plain}`. So only the `\thispagestyle{plain}` inside the `titlepage` environment would change anything, because the begin code of `titlepage` uses `\thispagestyle{empty}`. And if the table of contents would have more than one page, the `\thispagestyle{…}` would not change anything for the first page of the table of contents but for the last one (or even the next page).

Comment: @cabohah Right! Too much typing...